# How to show hidden form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a hidden form when click on button
my problem is when I click on the button the form is displayed for seconds then the page reload 
this is my code:

Java Script:

```
function show(){
    document.getElementById("theForm").style.display="block";
}
```

html :

```
<button id="search" onclick="show()">show</button>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="FormController/save" method = "POST" id="theForm" style="display: none">
```

Comment: what is in that form . show us full code

Comment: Try with the updated code which I made in question, the tags were not as per standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default behavior of `button` is `submit`, hence the `form` is submitted. You can use `type="button"` which doesn't have default behavior, thus it can be associated  with client-side event handlers.

```
<button type="button" id="search" onclick="show()">show</button>
```

---

Additionally, I would recommend you do get rid of of ugly inline click handlers and bind event handler using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
 document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener("click", show, false);
```

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" id="search">show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery as your tags says so you could do it like :

```
$('#seach').on('click', function(){
    $('#theForm').show();
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#search').on('click', function(){
  $('#theForm').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search">Show</button>
<br>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="FormController/save" method = "POST" id="theForm" style="display: none">
  MY FORM
</form>
```

Comment: sorry I am not using JQuery
Wrong tag

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Java Script:

            function show(){
            document.getElementById("theForm").style.display="block";
        }
html :

<input type="button" onclick="show()" id="search" value="show">
            </form>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="FormController/save" method = "POST" id="theForm" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){   
     $("#what").click(function() { //call event
         $(".hello").hide();//hide forms
         $('neededFormOnly').show();  //show only the needed form
         return false 
   });
 });
</script>
```